# Why is the Button enable not working when TextView has contents?

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uibutton

Likely a very simple rookie mistake going on here but I'm trying to make sure a button is disabled until a TextView has text in it.

I set

```
Button.isEnabled = false
```

and then added this code. I've tried variations of this code in various ways, I'm seemingly unable to attach it to the textView itself, I can't imagine why this wouldn't be working.

```
@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if(title.text != "")
    {
        Button.isEnabled = true
    }
    else
    {
        Button.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Thanks StackedOverflow Community ...

Comment: None of this has anything to do with SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set button's enabled with alpha to make the look better then set enabled/disabled through `valueChanged`

```swift
@IBOulet private weak var myButton: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        set(myButton, enabled: false)
    }
}

@IBAction private func valueChanged(_ sender: UITextView) {
  set(myButton, enabled: !sender.text.isEmpty)
}

private func set(_ button: UIButton, enabled: Bool) {
  button.isEnabled = enabled
  button.alpha = enabled ? 1 : 0.5
}
```